# Can't Read cookie in another page of my website PHP

Tags: php, cookies

I set cookie in one page

```
http://www.example.com/test.php
```

code is like this:

```
<?php
$cookie_name = "user";
$cookie_value = "Alex Porter";
setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30) , '/',
'.example.com' );
?>
<html>
<body>

<?php
if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
    echo "Cookie named '" . $cookie_name . "' is not set!";
} else {
    echo "Cookie '" . $cookie_name . "' is set!<br>";
    echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Its working. and print cookie will give right result.

Now i try to access same cookie in

```
http://www.example.com/test1.php
```

after loading

```
http://www.example.com/test.php
```

code:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
    echo "Cookie named '" . $cookie_name . "' is not set!";
} else {
    echo "Cookie '" . $cookie_name . "' is set!<br>";
    echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
}
?>
```

But its not working. Result:

Cookie named '' is not set!

I am Using Shared server in Godaddy

Comment: Where is `session_start()`?

Comment: @u_mulder sir where i use session_start() ? I am a beginer. I used session handling where i use session_start() at the top of script. for cookie also need session_start() in both page?

Comment: @u_mulder Sir used session_start(); in both page . but not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must define `$cookie_name = 'user';` at the beginning of your test1.php file. Variables are not shared between scripts unless you require them into each other.

Comment: Im glad you got it working. But can you explain how? Did my solution was useful?

Comment: Yes. I define $cookie_name = 'user';
code :
<?php
session_start();
$cookie_name = "user";
if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
    echo "Cookie named '" . $cookie_name . "' is not set!";
} else {
    echo "Cookie '" . $cookie_name . "' is set!<br>";
    echo "Value is: " . $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
}
?>

Comment: Nice! Then you could please mark the topic as solved!